# Is it possible to use simple past with "During the last week"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-continuous

I wanted to write a sentence about last/past week and I have doubts

> A1) During the last week I arrived home at 7
>
> A2) During the last week I was arriving at 7
>
> B1) During the past week I arrived home at 7
>
> B2) During the past week I arrived home at 7

Note that I want to talk about the whole week not a single day.

If none of the above senteces are right or natural, please give me the sentence that sound natural to you.

Comment: Last week I was getting home at 7.

Comment: Mind, **last week** and **the last week** are not the same in English.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "during the last week" is grammatical but for some reason it sounds awkward.  Native English speakers would be more likely to just say "last week" or "this past week".  With these expressions, "during" is redundant.

Native speakers do talk this way when emphasizing a duration of time.  It's fine to use the simple past with *during*, but again, it sounds odd when paired with "last week" or "past week".

> During the last week she **played** the violin twice.

This would require an unusual context in which I wanted to accurately emphasize how many times she played the violin in the given period.  More natural is:

> She **played** the violin twice **last week**.

*During* feels more useful when referring to events that themselves don't describe a period of time:

> During the campaign the candidate made many outrageous promises.
>
> I heard my friend snoring during class.
>
> It was during the war that he met his wife.

If you want to talk about actions that happen repeatedly over a period of time, simple past or present is fine.  It's natural to be explicit about how often these occur.

> This past week I **arrived** home **every night** at 7.
>
> Last week I **visited** my mother at the hospital **three times**.
>
> During this past week I **kept** meticulous records of **every time** I saw the man in the red beret walk by my house.

Comment: Thanks. What about my example, how can I put it into words that sound natural? I feel that it would be weird if I said " I arrived home at 7 last week".

Comment: @MasihK please see my edited answer.

Comment: So here "Last week" and "this past week" and "during this past week" are interchangable?

Comment: For me, yes.  I think this might be more personal style than *grammar*, though, and others might prefer "this last week".